# Old MSX computer -5v power

Tags: power-supply

I picked up an old Toshiba MSX computer with a duff power supply.

I need: Ground, +12v, +5v and -5v.

I've picked up a 12v power supply and I thought I could use a buck converter for the +5v, but I'm at a loss how I can get the -5v and how I can complete the circuit (can I use the negative terminal of the 5v for the -5v?).

Many thanks for any answers.

Comment: The current requirements are just as important as the voltage requirements.

Comment: What does "duff" mean?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: Nonfunctioning.

Comment: Might be worth trying to figure out what the -5v supply is used for. Likely it is low current, which could make using a PC supply with a -12v rail and a 7905 linear regulator to provide -5v from that a possibility.

Comment: @HandyHowie - I've discussed this with another MSX enthusiast who has replaced power supplies and he indicated that the minimum required for the 5v would be 1.2A

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Based on what I've found out the -5v is needed for the RAM chips (4116)

Comment: Hmm, IBB for 4116's seems to be a few hundred uA's so either there are an awful lot of them or something else is drawing that amp and a half.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options. Given your evident level of expertise, the simplest thing to do is to get three separate AC-input power supplies:

- 12VDC - connect the negative terminal to ground - this provides +12V
- 5VDC - connect the negative terminal to ground - this provides +5V
- 5VDC - connect the positive terminal to ground - this provides -5V

Comment: I would add that the 5V supply that provides -5V must have an **isolated** output. Most do, but I would keep it in mind while shopping.

Comment: @Elliot since Dave was talking about AC input supplies, they better *all* have isolated outputs anyway. Unless you want a new haircut...

Comment: Using multiple AC supplies may lead to sequencing issues.Even more - absence of some source (-5V for example) may lead to permanent damage.